# Tracking method invocations in Groovy closure

Tags: groovy, dsl, reactive-programming

I'm writing a small DSL for reactive evaluation, need help with metaprogramming in Groovy.

Sample DSL code:

```
Signal<Integer> a = var(1)
Signal<Integer> b = var(2)
Signal<Integer> c = signal { a(it) + b(it) }
```

The 'var' function creates new `Signal` instance.

The `signal` function needs a list of `Signal` instances inside the closure (references to `a` and `b` in example).

Working implementation:

```
interface Signal<T> {
    T now()
}

Signal.metaClass.call = { dependencies ->
    dependencies?.add(delegate)
    delegate.now()
}

def signal = { Closure<?> body ->
    def dependencies = new HashSet<>()
    body.call(dependencies)
    createSignal(dependencies, body)
}
```

Is there any way to awoit passing `it` variable, so sample looks like

```
Signal<Integer> a = var(1)
Signal<Integer> b = var(2)
Signal<Integer> c = signal { a() + b() }
```

**EDIT:**
Stub `Signal` implementation for testing:

```
class SignalStub<T> implements Signal<T> {
    T value
    Collection<Signal<?>> dependencies

    static def var(value) { new SignalStub<>(value: value, dependencies: [])}
    static def createSignal(deps, body) { new SignalStub<Object>(value: body.call(), dependencies: deps) }

    @Override
    T now() {
        return value
    }
}
```

Test case for DSL:

```
def a = var(1)
def b = var(2)

def c = signal { a() + b() }

assert c.now() == 3
assert c.dependencies.contains(a)
assert c.dependencies.contains(b)
```

Comment: what is `var(1)` and `var(2)` doing?

Comment: @tim_yates it creates new `Signal` instance

Answer (score 1):

The question is: "Is there a way to avoid passing the it variable?" 
Since a and b are local variables and local variables are not taking part in the MOP, it should be impossible to do using runtime meta programming.

Using a transform it is possible, but I don't know if you want to go that far here